# Python and scikit learn: The output of my model comes nan instead of category name

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I am working on an ML model that predicts the output category based on the input. I have a working model with no error, however, I am getting nan as output instead of the 'category' value.
The data I am working on is all text.

Here is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df=pd.read_excel('D:\\android\\medicare.xlsx')


X=df['Product Description'].fillna(' ')
Y=df['Category'].astype(str)

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
X_train,X_test,Y_train,Y_test=train_test_split(X,Y,test_size=.25,random_state=42)

from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
count_vector=CountVectorizer()
X_train_count=count_vector.fit_transform((X_train).values.astype('U'))

from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfTransformer
tfidf_transformer= TfidfTransformer()
X_train_tfidf=tfidf_transformer.fit_transform(X_train_count)
X_train_tfidf.shape

from sklearn.naive_bayes import MultinomialNB

clf = MultinomialNB().fit(X_train_tfidf, Y_train)


from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.externals import joblib
import pickle
text_clf=Pipeline([('vect',CountVectorizer()),('tfidf',TfidfTransformer()),('clf',MultinomialNB()),])
text_clf=text_clf.fit(X_train,Y_train)
joblib.dump(text_clf,'model.pkl')
X_test1=['SOTALOL 160MG CP SEC']
predicted=text_clf.predict(X_test1)
proab=text_clf.predict_proba(X_test1)
print (str(predicted[0]))
print (proab)
print (text_clf.classes_)
print (max(proab[0]))
```

Here is my output:
I am expecting a category code but the output comes as 'nan'.

```
nan
[[3.79853900e-06 2.84302863e-05 7.59252188e-06 ... 2.84280220e-05
  1.89960087e-06 4.28977861e-04]]
['153 Sm-SAMARIUM ACIDE ETHYLENEDIAMINETETRAMETHYLENE PHOSPHONIQUE'
 'ABAISSE LANGUE' 'ABATACEPT' ... 'solutions salines'
 'Électrodes ou câbles pour endoscopie'
 'Étiquettes médicales à usage général ']
0.8404466876175863
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This means that there are some values in `y` which are `nan` when you load the data. You convert the type of `y` to `string`, so those `nan` values are also converted to string `'nan'`, which is taken as a new class by the scikit-learn model.

Example:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
y = pd.Series(['a', 'b', np.nan]).astype(str)

type(y[2])
# Output: str

any(y.isna())
# Output: False
```

You can check if `'nan'` is a class in your model by doing this:

```
'nan' in text_clf.classes_
```

If it returns `True`, then maybe there is some problem in your `'xlsx'` file and the `'Category'` column is not filled completely and have some empty or NA values. You need to handle those rows before doing anything else.

Comment: @PavanRajput First you need to check why do you have nan values as targets in your file. Why are you using those samples which have nan values? It does not make any sense to remove nan values from the target that you are actually predicting.

Comment: is.na() is returning False.

Comment: @PavanRajput I know that. Check `df['Category'].isna()`.

Comment: thanks for the help some of the rows contain no values i will handle those and then proceed further. Thanks for the help.